# Should I call my API from my model or controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns

My question is mostly related to an architectural or design pattern for hierarchical models in Objective C. For background my app is relatively simple. In general it talks to a web service to retrieve and display things a user can follow. When someone follows something, the thing they are following is conceptually stored for access later by posting to the web service.

I would like advice on where the logic should go to manage the interaction between the web service and the group of things a user follows.

For example, is it appropriate to create a model object like `MyStuffModel` with an array property named `followedThings` that holds references to `AThingModel` objects? And if so, would the logic for refreshing from the web service, etc be written and executed in the model?

Potential code example

```
@interface MyStuffModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *followedThings;

- (void)refreshAllFollowedThingsFromWebService;

@end

@implementation MyStuffModel

- (void)refreshAllFollowedThingsFromWebService
{
    //call my API client (built on AFNetworking), get back a response
    //populate followedThings, notify a view controller, etc

}

@end
```

Or, should I not have a `MyStuffModel` object and manage the calls to my web service by calling my API client directly from a view controller?

In your experience, which approach is desired? Or is there another way?

Comment: Just nitpicking: `NSObject` is not part of ObjectiveC; it is part of NextStep/Cocoa, the most well-known framework using ObjectiveC. However this question is not really ObjectiveC or Cocoa specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do all of the networking from within the model. Here's an outline of how all the pieces fit together

- the controller tells the model which items to follow
- the model forwards that information to the server
- when the server has new information, it uses APNS to notify the model
- the model requests the new information from the server
- after the data transfer is complete, the model uses `NSNotificationCenter` to inform the controller that new information is available
- the controller reads the information from the model
- the controller updates the view with the new information

Using [Apple's Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) (APNS) allows your server to notify your app when new data is available. This helps reduce network traffic since your app doesn't have to constantly poll the server to determine when new data is available.  If you aren't familiar with APNS, there's one very important feature of the service that you need to be aware of (since it seems to be a point of confusion for many new users).  The service only guarantees delivery of the last message sent. So, for example, if the server gets 10 new items for a particular device, and sends 10 notifications to the device while the device is either off or in a tunnel, then the service is only guaranteed to deliver the 10th message. The point is that you can't use APNS to send any data from the server to the device, since some messages may be lost.  You should only use APNS to notify the device that data is available.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you.  One additional clarification that is mildly in-scope for this question...you recommend using `NSNotificationCenter` as a means by which to notify view controller(s). Do you think this approach is preferred in this situation over delegates or completion blocks?

Comment: Using `NSNotificationCenter` is the officially sanctioned way for a model to inform  other portions of the app that changes have occurred. The theory is that any number of objects in your app could be listening for the notification from the model. For example, in a split view controller on an iPad, both the master and the detail view controller could be listening for model updates.  But just because it's the official way, doesn't mean it's the only way to get the job done.

Comment: Very good and thank you. I believe there is a need for both approaches in my app. Completion blocks for specific controller interactions and `NSNotificationCenter` for broadcast messages, independent of app state.

Answer (score 0):

I always create model classes (and interfaces, no idea if thats applicable in ObjectiveC).
The model is in many cases a view of the database backend.

Your model class should hide the database access and provide a simple interface, for example using a `addNewFollower` method. This method should then (optionally do sanity checks) and persist this to the database backend.

This approach allows you to easily replace your database integration without touching the service layer at all. For example using an in-memory mock database for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I always create simple "dumb" objects for models, as they model the data, nothing more. If you're doing networking/api calls, I'd create a separate set of classes that deal strictly with API calls and utilize your models as the interchange data. Mixing data and functionality is always fishy to me.

Writing a clean, reusable, testable, and reliable API client, that can handle errors, parallel/serial calls, logging etc, requires quite a bit of code that really should be separated from your other application tiers. Data is just data, keep it clean, keep it simple.

The other thing is that some endpoints don't always return data exactly as it is defined in that 1 model where you are shoe-horning all of your code.

I wouldn't put it in the controllers either, I personally always create a different set of classes that can be used specifically for API calls, which also throw their own exceptions, handle serialization/de-serialization etc.